# Ubuntu 18.04 Dual Boot with Windows 10 not detecting partition

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows-10

I am trying to Install Ubuntu 18.04 so I can dual boot with my current Windows 10.

I have followed the instructions I have found online, but I get to the point where I need to select a disk partition, but it doesn't see anything.

[Partitions selection screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQTom.jpg)

I have created 100GB of unallocated space where I want to put Ubuntu. My disk management looks like this:
[Disk Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2a9q8.png)

I have disabled Secure Boot in my BIOS.

I have fixed the graphics issue with Nvidia by adding nomodeset to the grub file.

When I tried to use Gparted it only finds /dev/sda and can't find my unallocated space.

This is the Rufus confuration I used to make the Bootable USB.

[Rufus Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eRJ4.png)

For reference this is on a Lenovo Legion Y740.

Edit: Added pictures of BIOS settings for Storage:
[Storage Settings 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4mgk.png)
[Storage Settings 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MuKw.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: Your SATA disk controller is probably set to RAID mode. Let me know if it is, and I'll post an answer on how to change that. Also, nomodeset should only be used as a temporary workaround, not put permanently into GRUB.

Comment: I updated the original post to include pictures of my storage settings in BIOS.

Comment: Do you have Optane memory? Do you have Windows installed? Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: The result was AVCN17WW(V1.07)


I do not believe I have Optane memory.


Yes Windows 10. I am trying to install Ubuntu in addition

Comment: What brand/model system. Many need UEFI update and SSD firmware update, even if new as updates can be frequent. Also drives need to be set to AHCI, not RAID nor Intel RST. Best to have UEFI fast boot off, and must have Windows fast start up off. Be sure to boot in UEFI boot mode. Shows installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: I need the EXACT model # of the computer to check for BIOS versions. Lenovo Legion Y740-what?

Comment: Lenovo Legion Y740-15ICHg. It looks like Intel RST is active, but when i try to switch to AHCI is says all existing data stored on the drives will be erased. Is there a way to do it without erasing everything? EDIT: Just saw your post, will take a look

Comment: @AlexJ Do your backups first. Then do BIOS and SSD firmware updates. Retest Ubuntu install. Then you'll probably still need to do part #3 of my answer. And yes, that warning message comes up... but you have good backups, just in case, yes?

Comment: @AlexJ If my answer proves to be helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BIOS**

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS

**Note**: Check I have the correct web page for your model #

Lenovo Legion Y740-15ICHg

You have BIOS version AVCN17WW(V1.07). The latest BIOS version is AVCN21WW(V1.11) and can be downloaded [here.](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/pe/es/products/laptops-and-netbooks/legion-series/legion-y740-17ichg/downloads/ds506181)

**Samsung SSD firmware**

In Windows, download the `Samsung Magician` software [here](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/), and check your SSD firmware for an update.

**Ubuntu install problem**

**Note**: Have good backups before making these changes

You've got a single SSD set up in RAID mode, and the Ubuntu installer won't recognize your SSD until you switch your disk setting in the BIOS from RAID to AHCI.

Making that switch comes with some problems though, as Windows will no longer boot.

You don't need to reinstall Windows...

Below, you'll find two different ways to solve this problem. Some users found Choice #2 to be easier.

## Make sure to have a backup of your important Windows files!

**Choice #1:** Looking at this article https://samnicholls.net/2016/01/14/how-to-switch-sata-raid-to-ahci-windows-10-xps-13/ will show you how to make the change without having to reinstall Windows.

- Boot to Windows with your current SATA controller configuration
- Open `Device Manager`
- Expand `Storage Controllers` and identify the `Intel SATA RAID Controller`
- View properties of the identified controller
- On the Driver tab, click the Update driver… button
- Browse my computer…, Let me pick…
- Uncheck `Show compatible hardware`
- Select `Microsoft` as manufacturer
- Select `Microsoft Storage Spaces Controller` as model #
- Accept that `Windows cannot confirm that this driver is compatible`
- Save changes, reboot to BIOS and change RAID SATA Controller to AHCI
- Save changes and reboot normally, hopefully to Windows

Now you should be able to install Ubuntu in a dual-boot configuration.

**Choice #2:** See http://triplescomputers.com/blog/uncategorized/solution-switch-windows-10-from-raidide-to-ahci-operation/

- Right-click the Windows Start Menu. Choose `Command Prompt (Admin)`.
- If you don’t see `Command Prompt` listed, it’s because you have already been updated to a later version of Windows.  If so, use this method instead to get to the Command Prompt:
   -  Click the Start Button and type `cmd`
   - Right-click the result and select `Run as administrator`
- Type this command and press ENTER: `bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal`
   - If this command does not work for you, try `bcdedit /set safeboot minimal`
- Restart the computer and enter BIOS Setup (the key to press varies between systems).
- Change the SATA Operation mode to AHCI from either IDE or RAID (again, the language varies).
- Save changes and exit Setup and Windows will automatically boot to Safe Mode.
- Right-click the Windows Start Menu once more. Choose `Command Prompt (Admin)`
- Type this command and press ENTER: `bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot`
   - If you had to try the alternate command above, you will likely need to do so here also: `bcdedit /deletevalue safeboot`
- Reboot once more and Windows will automatically start with AHCI drivers enabled.

Comment: I completed the steps in the first method, but when I go to change from controller mode RST to AHCI it still gives me a warning saying that all existing data stored on drives will be erased when resetting controller mode. Am I going to need to recover from my backup with these methods?

Comment: @AlexJ Nobody has lost any data that I know of. Some people combined Choice #1 and Choice #2 to get it all done. Most people don't follow my suggestion that indicates that Choice #2 might be easier. I included the links to the original sources where the instructions came from, so if folks needed to read more, they could.

Comment: @AlexJ Status please...

Comment: I saw that you said choice 2 might be easier, but choice 1 was fairly straightforward.

I ended up trying (successfully) the install on an older laptop due to time constraints. I will try to finish this during this week. I will make sure to report back.

Comment: @AlexJ Good news! Remember the BIOS and SSD firmware updates. Please remember to accept my answer by clicking the checkmark icon that's just to the left of my answer. Thanks!